# get value - ajax'

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am sending this variable to other page, to make a validation.

However `print_r($_POST);` only show `Array ()`.

Normally we use serialize, is sent the name attribute, but in this case only is sent the variable with the text. So something like `$form = $_POST['data'];`  only works to

in firebug:

```
data="something"
```

but in my case i just send

```
something
```

**code**

```
 <?php $page = "someText"; ?>
```

JS

```
 default:
            $("#msg").fadeTo(200, 0.1, function() {
                $(this).html('success').fadeTo(900, 1);

                $.ajax({
                    url: "page_validation.php",
                    type: "post",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data:'<?php echo $page; ?>',          
                    success: function(data) {
                        $('#one').load('page.php');
                        }
                });
            });
            break;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try it like

```
$page = "someText";

 $.ajax({
   url: "page_validation.php",
   type: "post",
   dataType: "json",
   data:"postedvariable=<?php echo $page; ?>",       
   success: function(data) {
            $('#one').load('page.php'); 
   }
 });
```

and acces the varible in **page_validation.php** as **$_POST['postedvariable']**

also another option will be to use

```
$.post("page_validation.php",
{postedvariable:'<?php echo $page; ?>'},
function(data) {
  $('#one').load('page.php');
 });
```

whic looks even simpler than the $.ajax